# Particles that indicate surprise [も/まで]

Tags: grammar

It is my understanding that using the either the particle も or まで can both indicate surprise that the noun is included within some context.

(I'm not that advanced in Japanese yet so I apologise for mixing English and Japanese into the example. Hopefully I got the idea across).

Ex/

English: 
"Even children own phones!"

Japanese:
"childrenも phonesを own!"
v.s.
"childrenまで phonesを own!"

Are these particles interchangeable in this context?

Comment: I feel like まで would put emphasis on the ubiquity of phones, whereas も would emphasize that even *children* own phones. (Non-native and would not consider myself an expert)

Comment: By the way, it would be something like「こども『も・まで』けいたいをもってる」

Answer (score 5):

In this case, using 「まで」 would be just fine, but using 「も」 by itself would be a little too weak to serve the purpose of expressing one's surprise.

The most often used (therefore, most natural) particle choices here would be:

> 「こども + **まで/までも/でも/さえも/でさえも** + 携帯{けいたい}を持{も}っている。」

Among all those choices, 「まで」 and 「でも」 are on the informal side, and 「でさえも」 would be the most formal and emphatic.